# Date format issue, jQuery UI default date setting not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to set a default date, it works when I do the 12/29/2016 date format but won't work when I use 12-19-2016 format. How can I convert it to the 12/29/2016?

I added this piece of code:

```
    var businessDate = $("#businessDate").val();
    var date = new Date(businessDate);
```

Now, I get 12/28/2016 instead of 12/29/2016. How can I fix that?

```
$(function() {
    var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy", from = $("#startDate").datepicker({
        defaultDate : "+1w",
        changeMonth : true,
        changeYear : true,
        numberOfMonths : 1,
        beforeShowDay : $.datepicker.noWeekends
    }).on("change", function() {
        from.datepicker("option", "minDate", getDate(this));
    }), to = $("#endDate").datepicker({
        defaultDate : "+1w",
        changeMonth : true,
        changeYear : true,
        numberOfMonths : 1,
        beforeShowDay : $.datepicker.noWeekends
    }).on("change", function() {
        to.datepicker("option", "maxDate", getDate(this));
    });

    var businessDate = $("#businessDate").val(); //12-29-2019

    $("#startDate").datepicker("setDate", "12/29/2017"); // Works
    $("#startDate").datepicker("setDate", businessDate ); // Does not work
```

HTML

```
            <div class=rows>
                        <span class="label"><strong>Date Range:</strong></span>
                <div id="dateToAndFrom">                
                    <span class="dateFrom"> <label id="dateLabel" for="from">From</label>
                        <input type="text" id="startDate" name="startDate">
                    </span> 

                    <span class="dateTo"> <label id="dateLabel" for="to">To</label>
                        <input type="text" id="endDate" name="endDate">
                    </span>
                </div>
                </div>

            </div>

    <input type="hidden" id="businessDate" name="businessDate"
            value="${businessDate}" />
```

Comment: Well, you can replace "-" with "/".

Comment: I need it in the "/" format.

Comment: can you show us the html code?

Comment: I suppose you had in your code the getDate function somewhere, righ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this:

```
var businessDate = $("#businessDate").val(); //12-29-2019

businessDate = new Date(businessDate)
$("#startDate").datepicker("setDate", businessDate );
```

Comment: Did that work for you? See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j_mmontero/mLorfrgL/

Comment: It worked but I get 12/28/2016 instead of 12/29/2016.

Comment: @AppSensei I got the right date! Did you try my fiddle?

Comment: Glad I could help!!